# How to Limit # of Rows Returned using Openquery on a Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, openquery

I have an AS400 Linked Server, and I'm trying to run some queries and get some sample sets, but I can't figure out how to limit the number of rows returned.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED, 'SELECT * FROM LINKED.APLUS.CUS WHERE CMSUSP != ''S'' LIMIT 100')
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED, 'SELECT TOP(100) * FROM LINKED.APLUS.CUS WHERE CMSUSP != ''S'' ')
```

I know I can add the TOP to the SELECT FROM OPENQUERY, but I'm trying to not have the AS400 return 100k rows when I only need 100.

Comment: Using openquery, you pass a statement to the other database engine to execute. So any functionality you desire must be implemented in the sql dialect used by that engine. So - does DB2 (presumably - might help if you provide specific information) implement that in some fashion?

Comment: And seems to me that LIMIT should do what you want. Did it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience with an AS400 system, I believe you're looking for *FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY*

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ... FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY
```

In your example that would be:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED, 'SELECT * FROM LINKED.APLUS.CUS WHERE CMSUSP != ''S'' FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY')
```

It is recommended to include an `ORDER BY` to ensure that the results are consistent.

See this question and answer for additional details: [How to do SQL select top N ... in AS400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850423/how-to-do-sql-select-top-n-in-as400)